# Office365 licenses management with powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

We have a hybrid office365, I wrote a script that creates users in our AD and it assigns our default office365 package. Everything works, but since we don't usually have free licenses, I need to log into office365, buy the new licenses and then run the script.

The question is: is it actually possible to **buy** licenses from powershell or exists some magic way to do that? I don't mean assign licenses, that's easy, but buy new licenses ready to be assigned.

It's not a huge problem to buy some licenses before running the script, it just doesn't make sense to run a script if I need to use the dashboard anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: @iwasatenbyagrue
I appreciate the correction, but your edit leaves people thinking that I didn't spent a second searching for this answer, while I've read every single post on google about this argument with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No, I don't think so.

For Enterprise tenants, licenses are generally purchased ("Reserved") through the Volume License Service Center.  From here, processes may vary (resellers, etc.), but eventually the tenant ends up with new licenses.

For Retail tenants, a transaction needs to occur.  It's been a while, but you pick the licenses from a big list, and then there is a credit card order processing page, then licenses appear in the tenant.

Either way, there are no MSOL nor Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets to add a license to a tenant.

Comment: I usually go under "Subscriptions" of our office365 admin page, and I just "Add" licenses from there, a credit card is already linked. So, because is that simple, I just thought some kind of powershell command could achieve that. I'm really disappointed, I wanted my script to work without any intervention and this makes it impossible :(

Comment: Well, after the hours spent on this and your answer, I think this question can be closed, maybe in future..